# Usage bar generation with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, graphs

I would like to generate usage bar (like this one):
[image]

I dont know where to start.. is it possible to do it with TikZ ?
Any example will help a lot.

Thank you

Comment: It is possible with Ti*k*Z (and `pgplots` may be more convenient). The very least you may want to do is to at least specify the way you want to set the data, and provide a sample set of data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The weights are automatically standardized.

(Somehow I confused the name with "progress bar", please ignore this mistake)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.misc}



\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \g_pb_colors_clist
% these are the colors used by the progress bar
% number of items should not exceed the number of colors here
% the last color will always be used for the last item in the bar
\clist_gset:Nn \g_pb_colors_clist {
    6495ed,
    006400,
    00008b,
    b03060,
    ff4500,
    ffd700,
    7fff00,
    00ffff,
    ff00ff,
    ffdab9,
    a0a0a0
}

% the dimensions of progress bar (in cm)
\fp_new:N \g_pb_width_fp
\fp_new:N \g_pb_height_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_pb_width_fp {5.0}
\fp_gset:Nn \g_pb_height_fp {0.5}

% radius of rounded corners (in cm)
\fp_new:N \g_pb_corner_radius_fp
\fp_gset:Nn \g_pb_corner_radius_fp {0.2}

% helper function to get names of colors
\cs_set:Npn \pb_color_name:n #1 {
    pb-internal-color-\int_to_alph:n{#1}
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \color_define:nnn \definecolor
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_define:nnn {xnx}

% declare all colors
\int_step_inline:nn {\clist_count:N \g_pb_colors_clist} {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {\clist_item:Nn \g_pb_colors_clist {#1}}
    \color_define:xnx {\pb_color_name:n {#1}}{HTML}{\l_tmpa_tl}
}

% the last color
\tl_new:N \g_pb_last_color_tl
\tl_gset:Nx \g_pb_last_color_tl {\pb_color_name:n {\clist_count:N \g_pb_colors_clist}}


\cs_set:Npn \__pb_node_template:nnn #1#2#3 {
    \node[pbnode,#1]~at~(#2~cm,#3~cm)~{};
}

\cs_set:Npn \__pb_draw_left:nn #1#2 {
    \fill[#1]
      (0~cm,0~cm) --
      ++(#2~cm,0~cm)  --
      ++(0,-\fp_use:N \g_pb_height_fp~cm) {[rounded~corners=\fp_use:N \g_pb_corner_radius_fp~cm] --
      ++(-#2~cm,0~cm) --
      cycle}
      {};
}

\cs_set:Npn \__pb_draw_middle:nn #1#2 {
    \fill[#1]
      (0~cm,0~cm) --
      ++(#2~cm,0~cm)  --
      ++(0,-\fp_use:N \g_pb_height_fp~cm) --
      ++(-#2~cm,0~cm) --
      cycle
      {};
}

\cs_set:Npn \__pb_draw_right:nn #1#2 {
    \fill[#1]
      (0~cm,0~cm) {[rounded~corners=\fp_use:N \g_pb_corner_radius_fp~cm] --
      ++(#2~cm,0~cm)  --
      ++(0,-\fp_use:N \g_pb_height_fp~cm)} --
      ++(-#2~cm,0~cm) --
      cycle
      {};
}

\cs_set:Npn \__pb_draw_both:nn #1#2 {
    \fill[#1, rounded~corners=\fp_use:N \g_pb_corner_radius_fp~cm]
      (0~cm,0~cm) --
      ++(#2~cm,0~cm)  --
      ++(0,-\fp_use:N \g_pb_height_fp~cm) --
      ++(-#2~cm,0~cm) --
      cycle
      {};
}


% helper function to get the correct color
\cs_set:Npn \pb__fetch_color:nN #1#2 {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} = {\clist_count:N #2} {
        \g_pb_last_color_tl
    } {
        \pb_color_name:n {#1}
    }
}

\clist_new:N \l_pb_tmpa_clist
\clist_new:N \l_pb_tmpb_clist
\clist_new:N \l_pb_tmpc_clist
\seq_new:N \l_pb_tmpa_seq
\fp_new:N \l_pb_tmpa_fp
\fp_new:N \l_pb_tmpb_fp
\fp_new:N \l_pb_tmpc_fp
\tl_new:N \l_pb_tmpa_tl
\tl_new:N \l_pb_tmpb_tl
\int_new:N \l_pb_tmpa_int
\int_new:N \l_pb_tmpb_int

\cs_set:Npn \pb_progress_bar:nn #1#2 {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \clist_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_clist {#2}
    \int_compare:nNnF {\clist_count:N \l_pb_tmpa_clist} = 
        {\clist_count:N \l_pb_tmpb_clist} {
        \GenericError{}{progress~bar~error}
            {}{number~of~items~does~not~match~the~number~of~weights}
    }
    \int_compare:nNnT {\clist_count:N \l_pb_tmpa_clist} > 
        {\clist_count:N \g_pb_colors_clist} {
        \GenericError{}{progress~bar~error}
            {}{number~of~progress~bar~items~exceeds~number~of~colors}
    }
    % compute total weights
    \fp_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_fp {0.0}
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_clist {
        \fp_add:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_fp {##1}
    }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpc_fp {0.0}
    
    % determine drawing range
    \int_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_int {1}
    \int_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_int {\clist_count:N \l_pb_tmpa_clist}
    
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_clist {
      \fp_compare:nNnT {##1} > {0} {
        \clist_map_break:
      }
      \int_incr:N \l_pb_tmpa_int
    }
    
    \clist_set_eq:NN \l_pb_tmpc_clist \l_pb_tmpb_clist
    \clist_reverse:N \l_pb_tmpc_clist
    \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_pb_tmpc_clist {
      \fp_compare:nNnT {##1} > {0} {
        \clist_map_break:
      }
      \int_decr:N \l_pb_tmpb_int
    }
    
    % draw progress bar
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \int_compare:nNnTF {\l_pb_tmpa_int} = {\l_pb_tmpb_int} {
            \fp_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_fp {
                \g_pb_width_fp
            }
            \tl_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {
                color=\pb__fetch_color:nN {\l_pb_tmpa_int} \l_pb_tmpa_clist,
            }
            \exp_args:NV \__pb_draw_both:nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {\fp_use:N \l_pb_tmpb_fp}
        } {
        \int_step_inline:nnn {\l_pb_tmpa_int} {\l_pb_tmpb_int} {
                % compute width
                \fp_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_fp {
                    \clist_item:Nn \l_pb_tmpb_clist {##1} / \l_pb_tmpa_fp * \g_pb_width_fp
                }
                \tl_set:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {
                    color=\pb__fetch_color:nN {##1} \l_pb_tmpa_clist,
                    xshift=\fp_use:N\l_pb_tmpc_fp~cm,
                }
                % call corresponding drawing command
                \int_case:nnF {##1} {
                    {\l_pb_tmpa_int} {
                        \exp_args:NV \__pb_draw_left:nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {\fp_use:N \l_pb_tmpb_fp}
                    }
                    {\l_pb_tmpb_int} {
                        \exp_args:NV \__pb_draw_right:nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {\fp_use:N \l_pb_tmpb_fp}
                    }
                } {
                    \exp_args:NV \__pb_draw_middle:nn \l_pb_tmpa_tl {\fp_use:N \l_pb_tmpb_fp}
                }
                % update offset
                \fp_add:Nn \l_pb_tmpc_fp {\l_pb_tmpb_fp}
            }
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
    % construct legend
    \seq_clear:N \l_pb_tmpa_seq
    \int_step_inline:nn {\clist_count:N \l_pb_tmpa_clist} {
        \seq_put_right:Nx \l_pb_tmpa_seq {
            \exp_not:N\item
            [\exp_not:N\textcolor{\pb__fetch_color:nN {##1} \l_pb_tmpa_clist}{$\exp_not:N\blacksquare$}] {
                \clist_item:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_clist {##1}
            }
        }
    }
    \par\begin{itemize*}
        \seq_use:Nn \l_pb_tmpa_seq {}
    \end{itemize*}
}

\newcommand{\progressbar}[2]{
    \pb_progress_bar:nn {#1}{#2}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
\progressbar{E, A, Media, Apps, Photos, Other, B, C, D}{0, 0, 1,2,3,4, 0, 0, 0}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
\progressbar{A,B,C,D,E}{0,0,1,0,0}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{6cm}
\centering
\progressbar{lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit,amet,consectetur,adipiscing,elit,sed,do,eiusmod}
    {4, 5, 7, 1, 2, 5, 7, 9, 3, 6, 4}
\end{minipage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi .. there is a small bug in code.. if the first argument is 0, then the left border is not rounded.. can you fix that ?

Comment: @Anya93 updated.

Comment: Thank you now its almost perfect :) .. the right border is not rounded in some cases.. for example \progressbar{a,b,c,d}{0,8,0,0}

Comment: @Anya93 Well, it is a special case when there is essentially only one bar. In that case, you only need to draw a rounded rectangle. Do you want me to fix it?

Comment: If it is not a problem for you.. that would be perfect.. thank you

Comment: @Anya93 I just updated it as well. If the input is not all zeros, you should be fine.